# Angular toggle item in array always removing first value from array and ignoring given value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get a button click toggle a given value from an array.

So here is the array with all the values:

```
values = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
```

Here I execute the toggleTest method and pass string value of 'one'

```
<button (click)="toggleTest('one')"></button>
```

Finally here is should remove or add the value from the values array, depending if it exists or not.

```
toggleTest(value) {
   // if value exists in this.values then remove it ... else add it.
   So I tried this:

   if (this.values.includes(value)) {
      // it's there so lets remove it
      this.values.splice(value, 1);
   } else {
     // its not there so lets add it
     this.values.push(value, 1);
   }

}
```

When I try this it removes the first entry all the time and ignores the value given...it just removes one from the values array.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or
> replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place. To
> access part of an array without modifying it, see slice().

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
> returns the new length of the array.

```
toggleTest(val){

   if (this.values.includes(val)) {
      // it's there so lets remove it
     let index = this.values.indexOf(val);
     this.values.splice(index, 1);
   } else {
     // its not there so lets add it
     this.values.push(val);
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to push the val back to a defined position? At the moment it's changing it's order when I toggle it back on

Answer (score 0):

The splice function takes an index as its first parameter, not the value itself (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#parameters)).

So you could replace this:

```
this.values.splice(value, 1);
```

with this:

```
let index = this.values.indexOf(value);
this.values.splice(index, 1);
```